# Laravel 5.8 - Can't resolve instance from service container after update from 5.7 to 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

- Laravel Version: 5.8.11
- PHP Version: 7.1.26 (Homestead) - but also tested with 7.2 with same result

Since updating from 5.7 to 5.8, I can't resolve an instance anymore. It returns a string and I get `Trying to get property of non-object`.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

I bind the instance in a Middleware with:

```php
$globals = new Globals();
app()->instance('App\Helpers\Globals', $globals);
$globals->brows_browser = Agent::browser();
```

when trying to resolve it later (for example in web.php) with:

```php
$browser = resolve('App\Helpers\Globals')->brows_browser;
```

I get an error exception `Trying to get property of non-object`. $browser is a string "Helpers\Globals" and not an object. Was working fine in all Laravel versions before.

```php
namespace App\Helpers;

class Globals
{
    public $brows_browser;
    public $brows_device;
    public $brows_platform;
    public $brows_version;
}
```

I also tried to bind the instance in the route (web.php) and it produced the same result.

When I look at `resolve('App\Helpers\Globals')`, it is a string "App\Helpers\Globals" and not an object.

Anyone any idea? Could this be a bug in L5.8?

thanks

**UPDATE:**

It is not a bug.
I have `goetas-webservices/xsd2php-runtime` installed with composer and that's causing problems. I really have no idea why and what to do about it though.

These are the dependencies installed. I'm a bit at a dead end as I need that package:

```
Package operations: 17 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing jms/metadata (2.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/exception (1.17.01.16): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/event (1.17.01.13): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/consistency (1.17.05.02): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/zformat (1.17.01.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/protocol (1.17.01.14): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/iterator (2.17.01.10): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/visitor (2.17.01.16): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/ustring (4.17.01.16): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/compiler (3.17.08.08): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/regex (1.17.01.13): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/math (1.17.05.16): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/stream (1.17.02.21): Loading from cache
  - Installing hoa/file (1.17.07.11): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.6.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing jms/serializer (2.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing goetas-webservices/xsd2php-runtime (v0.2.9): Loading from cache
jms/serializer suggests installing doctrine/collections (Required if you like to use doctrine collection types as ArrayCollection.)
Writing lock file
```

UPDATE 2:

I drilled further down and it seems that hoa/compiler (specifically hoa/stream) is incompatible with Laravel 5.8

hoa/compiler is a dependency of jms/serializer.

That really sucks because jms/serializer is irreplaceable for us!

Comment: What happens if you try to resolve it just after binding?

Comment: I already tried. Same error.

Comment: Are you certain there is no code overwriting `$browser`? Did you also update PHP or just Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Laravel bug but an incompatibility with hoa/compiler (specifically hoa/stream).

hoa/compiler is a dependency of jms/serializer.

So for the moment jms/serializer won't play nice with Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 0):

simple bind like this in laravel 5.8 take care will be registered within service providers,

```php
$this->app->bind('App\Helpers\Globals', function () {
   return new App\Helpers\Globals();
});
```

You may use the make

```php
$globals = $this->app->make('App\Helpers\Globals');
```

Comment: $this->app is not available in a Middleware as far as I know. That's why I had to use app().